# Navigation Package Dependencies

Tags: ros, navigation, stack, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

My question is a repeat of [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/10775/navigation-tutorial-dependencies/).

I'm trying to set up the navigation stack on a robot possessing only odometry sensors (wheel encoder, IMU published to `/odom /imu`). No camera/laser. The robot is also using `robot_state_publisher` to publish the transformations between robot coordinates.

I want to use only odometry sources (wheel encoder, IMU) to navigate the robot, so my plan is to use [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) to fuse the odometry data and use [fake_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/fake_localization) to localize the robot on the known map.

The [navigation tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/) says that we should create a package:

```
roscreate-pkg my_robot_name_2dnav move_base my_tf_configuration_dep my_odom_configuration_dep my_sensor_configuration_dep
```

So the question is what should I put instead of `my_tf_configuration_dep my_odom_configuration_dep my_sensor_configuration_dep`

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191971/navigation-package-dependencies/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-09-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-09-08**:
Which tutorial?

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-09-08**:
http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Those packages refer to the results of the previous linked tutorials. In sections 2.1 2.2 and 2.3

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0